# SQLiteOpenHelper crashes Android application

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper

I followed a tutorial on how to handle SQLite databases using the android SDK. My Problem is that the application crashes when i call the method "getUsername()". What am I doing wrong?

```
package racenet.racenet;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class Preferences extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "racenet.racenet.db";

    Preferences(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE settings(key TEXT, value TEXT)");

        values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("user_name", "");
        getWritableDatabase().insert("settings", null, values);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {

    }

    public String getUsername() {

        Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().query("settings", new String[]{"value"},
            "key = 'user_name'", null, null, null, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        String username = c.getString(0);
        c.close();
        return username;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi, try this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE settings (key TEXT, value TEXT);");

    values = new ContentValues();

    // First argument of the put method is a column name
    // Second argument is an inserted value
    values.put("key", "user_name");
    values.put("value", "user_value");

    db.insert("settings", null, values);
}

// This method will drop your table and create a new one if you have changed 
// the database version
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS settings");

    onCreate(db);
}
```

Comment: also add some descriptions with the code snippet..that can help more :)

Comment: I can also suggest to store table names and column names in the private variables of the class. It will create more flexible way to make any future changes to the database and to write select/update/delete/insert logic.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that will for sure crash your application is that you do not close the database object you use in your method. You will need to rewrite it like that:

```
public String getUsername() {
    SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().query("settings", new String[]{"value"},
        "key = 'user_name'", null, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    String username = c.getString(0);
    c.close();
    database.close();
    return username;
}
```

**EDIT** Extending my answer to be more complete, using @slukian observation: You should not call `getWritableDatabase()` or `getReadableDatabase()` from within the `onCreate` or `onUpgrade` methods. Actually you don't even need to. Rewrite this method to:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE settings(key TEXT, value TEXT)");
    values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("user_name", "");
    db.insert("settings", null, values);
}
```

Note that I am just using the passed-in `db` object, just like you did several lines above.

Comment: You will need to add the error logs if you want to help you sort out the problems. As you see even without this information we managed to find two bugs in your program (did you see the edit due to @slukian comment?)

Answer (score 0):

you getting error because you written

```
c.moveToFirst();
```

without checking `c` has rows or not..

anyways..
c doesnt have rows cause you not added rows correctly..

just **add values correctly** like mentioned in **"Taras Feschuk" 's answer.**

and whenever you write `c.moveToFirst()` ..first check `if(c.getCount()>0)`